# How to integrate browser stack in cucumber framework using JAVA

Tags: browserstack

I am using cucumber frameowrk using JAVA, Now i have to run my tests in Browserstack. Can anyone help me how we can do this in JAVA,

I could see a link below which explians for ruby. But i need to know how we can do this in JAVA.

https://www.browserstack.com/automate/cucumber-integration

Comment: You can refer their sample github repo: https://github.com/browserstack/cucumber-java-browserstack

Comment: But how to inject this code to my Framework?

Comment: You only need to do the following changes to make it run on browserstack - change the hub URL in setup() or equivalent method in your test framework to browserstack's hub url. else share a working sample or gist of what you are trying to achieve.